# Android Manifest, how to disable launcher icon for lower api

Tags: android, accessibility

i have an accessibility application ive written, but on android 4.0 and higher, the api allows for a settings activity to be set. This defeats the purpose of having a launcher entry. Is there a way to single out 4.0 and higher systems in the manifest to not have the launcher icon?

EDIT: solution

I subclassed the original settings to a JB/ICS one. this is pretty uncessesary at this point, but if something JB/ICS specific is added to the app, it would probably be good in the long run to keep them seperate.

thanks alanv, your snippet did still help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can selectively disable an activity based on the platform version. Add an activity alias for your Settings activity and set the enabled attribute to a platform-specific value. This will ensure that it only shows up in the Launcher when you need it to.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MySettingsActivity"
    . . . >
</activity>

<activity-alias
    android:name=".MyActivityAlias"
    android:label="@string/settings"
    android:targetActivity=".MySettingsActivity"
    android:enabled="@bool/show_settings">
        <intent-filter>
        . . .
        </intent-filter>
</activity-alias>
```

values-v14/bool.xml:

```
<bool name="show_settings">false</bool>
```

values/bool.xml:

```
<bool name="show_settings">true</bool>
```

Comment: thats amazing feature i never know

Comment: 2 things happen. one putting activity-alias causes a malformed manifest error on install.  making the other changes also doesnt result in the desired effect.
When the bool results in false, it also removes the settings button that points to this app notifications

Comment: Fixed a typo in the XML snippet. Per the docs for activity-alias, make sure your targetActivity attribute matches the name attribute of an <activity> element that precedes the alias in the manifest.

Comment: your xml snippet is also missing android:name, which was giving me the malformed manifest. Also following your method still causes the application to become disabled.

i updated the OP with my solution